# How to get the XML ressouces of the android compatibiliy pack

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using the Android Compatibility Pack v4 (android-support-v4.jar) for my app.

I created a custom TabIndicator layout, but I want to use the default background!
The default background is dependant to the platform

- On 2.3.x it is [focused: lightgrey; pressed: yellow; none: darkgrey]
- On 4.0.x it is [focused: lightblue; pressed: midblue; none: darkblue]

Please see the attached screenshot for an example of the default colouring.
[image: The Background I am searching for]

What do I have to add to my `android:background` to get this background?

Comment: The source code to the Android Support Library is in your SDK, where the JAR for the library is.

Comment: I already checked that directory. The only files to be found are *.JAVA files.

Comment: It's a JAR, so there are no resources for the Android Support Library. Of course, there is no `TabIndicator` in the Android Support Library either. You will have to first determine what class you are referring to (`PagerTabStrip` is in the Android Support Library, though your screenshots appear to be of the ancient `TabHost`), then read the Java source code to see what it does.

Comment: The Graphical effects are the same as if you go to `Settings > Manage Apps`, so these Backgrounds I am searching must be somewhere is the system. I hoped that I just ave to include this already existing file to get what I want. Well seems, as I have to recreate the background for each android version I want to cover. Thanks!